# Inner joining one table against many others

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table **A** with  columns (Id,Value)
and a table **B** with Columns (BId,Id,..)
and a table **C** with columns (CId,Id,...)

I need to perform an inner join on these tables as follows

```
 select a.Id,a.Value from A a
 inner join B b on b.Id=a.Id
 inner join C c on c.Id=a.Id
 where <many conditions on table B and C>
```

How can i achieve the same. Now when i just run the query

```
 select a.Id,a.Value from A a
 inner join B b on b.Id=a.Id
 inner join C c on c.Id=a.Id
```

it doesnt return anything.. please help.

FYI when i run the joins separately it gives me the rows. I just want a union of them...

Sample data:

A 
1
2
3

B 
2

C 
3

then i want to select

A 
2
3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means you have no matching rows between A and B, or between A and C. This implies no matching rows between B and C too.

Comment: ihv matching rows between A and B and B and C but just not on B and C. is that a prob?

Comment: also when i run the joins separately it gives me the rows. I just want a union of them...

Comment: @Michelle: So, do you have matching rows between B and C or you don't?

Comment: Your join is asking to list all rows from A, B, and C where the Id of A matches the Id of B AND C. So if B and C have no matching Ids you should not return anything from any of the above queries.

Comment: nope i dont.. thats the whole point i want an union

Comment: @james I kinda ustood the same but i dnt know hw i should go abt solving my prob. can you guys help?

Comment: @Michelle: give us sample data then please. A UNION is not a JOIN...

Answer (score 2):

So, following your comments, it appears that you want something like this:

```
select a.Id,a.Value from A a
 inner join B b on b.Id=a.Id
where <many conditions on table B>
UNION ALL
SELECT a.Id, a.Value from A
 inner join C c on c.Id=a.Id
 where <many conditions on table C>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fields match on ID from A -> B and A -> C and you dont have any other join condition, you should be able to see the matching rows.

I could not understand your point about how the B and C Id do not match. if a.id=b.id and a.id=c.id, Doesn't it automatically imply b.id = c.id?

Anyways, in situations like these, I try to do outer join of A on B and C and see if the rows that I think are matching in fact do exist.

```
select a.Id,a.Value from A a
 left outer join B b on b.Id=a.Id
 left outer join C c on c.Id=a.Id
 where (b.id is not null or c.id is not null) 
       /* Matching record found in b or c */
```

**EDIT:** Based on your requirement, you can use the approach that Lamak suggested above (Using UNION Alls) or if you are certain that for each record in A, you will only have one record in B and one in C at most and only one column, you can use the [scalar sub query approach](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3407911/Scalar-Sub-Queries-in-SQL-Server.htm).

Comment: btw abt ur comment.. why isnt this posssible b=a and c=d where a and d are  entries in A and b in B and c in C..

Comment: Nothing wrong with outer joins as such, but the result set that you are looking for is not really based on joins. If you want to look at outer joins for this question, then at the end you should have another condition saying (b.id is not null or c.id is not null), because your record from a should be considered if either b or c has a matching record.